# php чтение больших файлов по url пакетами или построчно

Tags: php, файлы, url

Предположим есть файл 5 гигов, есть ссылка на него. Как считывать его пакетами(кусками) или построчно, что бы не захломлять оперативу принимающего сервера? Я в курсе что по сети данные передаются пакетами, но как тогда пакетную информацию перевести в текстовую информацию?
Этот вопрос не о том дайте мне готовое решение, это вопрос о том какими технологическими решениями это достигается. Немного читал про сокеты, но в этой ситуации необходим доступ к серваку, отдающем файл(может неправильно понял). А может в этом случае необходимо работать с HTTP - заставлять его ждать, посылая ответы что пакет не прошел, а тем временем уже декодировать и обрабатывать эту информацию.
Я не нашел внятный ответ на этот вопрос в официальной документации php и на курсах этому не учат.
Также выяснил что [CUrl может останавливать и возобновлять соединения](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-pause.php), но как это применить не понял

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: Про генераторы я в курсе @E_p . Эта технология позволяет загружать в оперативную память компьютера результат работы одного цикла. Если вы предлагаете использовать это для чтения файла по URL - то подскажите пожалуйста способ получения первой строки файла - в момент загрузки этого файла по URL(как получить любую строчку из собственного файла знают все - на то есть стандартные функции php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php. Если  `allow_url_fopen` включено, то ничего мудрить не надо, работает как с локальным файлом.